# How do I add an existing .class to an existing eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

how do I add an existing class into an existing project. I've got the file "Something.class" and in the code I do a

```
something window = new Something();
```

But it remains underlined in red. Does someone know how do I fix this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not already part of your workspace, it should be enough just to File -> Import and then find the class you want included.  If it's already part of the workspace, then Tommi's suggestion should do it.

Comment: Hmm, ctrl->space doesn't seem to do what I thought it did.  You may have better luck by hitting ctrl-shift-O (or right clicking inside your code editor window and going to Source -> Organize Imports)

Answer (score 1):

Also note, that Java is case sensitive. So in

something window = new Something();

something and Something are two different classes :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class into the referencing class. Ctrl + Space (while highlighting the classname) should do the trick in Eclipse.

Comment: It's still giving me an error. I've imported the library in project properties->java build path->Libraries->Add external class Folder and then selecting the directory containing the class, but to no avail....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jar file that has the class `something` to your project and import it your class.